# Can we copy site settings (Hide Left Navigation bar) across Main and Meta?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, left-navigation, profile-page

As the title says, currently Users have to enable/disable navigation bar settings individually for [Main](https://stackoverflow.com) in [Main site preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current) and for [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com) in [Meta site preferences](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current).

Can we have a common setting for this? Or at least, allow a user to copy the settings across sites in order to have a uniform experience in not only Stack Overflow's main and meta but also other Stack Exchange communities (similar to copying profile data).

Comment: I was just asking myself the same question, I find the space it takes up pretty annoying..

Comment: Did my rage turn you to this? [background context](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/42906342#42906342)

Comment: @KarelG partly :p.. I was thinking of posting it anyway. It was annoying when I tried to toggle

Comment: Exactly my thoughts when I: 1) first see it on SO 2) switch to meta after that to ask/search question about it. Left navigation is **absolutely useless** for 99.99% of users. I have no clue why it's ON by default.

Comment: It would be good to have such an option right on the sidebar. I've only found out how to disable this ugly piece of the website through this question.

Comment: @Sinatr because more white-space is more real estate to be sold as advertisement space. On by default means more people will see it, especially the non-logged on users who can't turn it off anyway. Site's quality is being sacrificed once again to the Mammon of money.

Comment: I'll go a step further, can there be a way to copy it across all of SE when it starts getting rolled out beyond SO?

Comment: Yes with a user script you can

Comment: I made a userscript (Which I called VisualCrumbs) that changes the way some things are displayed, including changing the page body margins to waste less space. There are a couple other minor changes this userscript makes that I believe also work well for the site. If you're interested in this, or want to contribute to the project, you can go to https://github.com/GrumpyCrouton/Userscripts/ - https://image.ibb.co/bUFLSy/NO_WASTED_SPACE.png

Comment: I hope SE implements global settings, but, based on past refusals to do so, doubt they will. As for the "Hide Left Navigation bar setting": Because I don't want the left-sidebar appearing on any site, I created [Left-sidebar in the Topbar](//stackapps.com/q/7928/29529), which moves the left-sidebar into the topbar on all SE sites which have the left-sidebar, regardless of the preference set on each individual site. Installing this userscript is functionally equivalent to having selected an SE network-wide preference to "Hide left navigation". You don't need to set the preference on each site.

Comment: At the very least, the sidebar should by default not be visible on my tiny tablet in landscape mode. Only half of the page is usable between the two sidebars.

Comment: In wide monitors, lot of white space is visible. unnecessary effort on scrolling .

Comment: Didnt realize it was completed.. Works great! Thanks @JoeFriend